# textcleaner not found error on powershell

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, imagemagick

Iam trying to run the textcleaner script on windows powershell(bash)

```
textcleaner.sh -g -e normalize -f 50 -o 10 -s 10 "F:\Testing\input\input.tif" "F:\Testing\output\input.tif"
```

I get an error textcleaner.sh: command not found

how to fix the issue. The file is running from within the textcleaner folder.

Comment: Why are you expecting a bash shell script to work on Windows? **PowerShell cannot run bash scripts.**  You might be able to run it within WSL2.

Comment: Yes,WSL2 is active  cph@Cph:/mnt/c/Users/Admin$

Comment: It sounds like you are NOT running it from within WSL2. Can you provide a screenshot?